# Outlook 365 Web Add-in - Context menu from Mail Item

Tags: javascript, outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-api

Outlook 365 **Web Add-in** - Context menu from Mail Item

Is this something that is still supported in the new Web Add-in model? From the documentation it appears that it is **NOT Supported**. I am looking for someone in a solid position to definitively confirm this so that we can move on to other potential solutions.

Extension Points Reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my research, the context menu from Mail Item is not supported in Web Add-in model.

However, You might reference the related post and it can meet your requirement.

Please see [Add Outlook Web Addin Function to context menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48750675/add-outlook-web-addin-function-to-context-menu)

Solutions: Outlook Web Add-ins allow customizing the ribbon by adding commands only. Read more about that in the [Add-in commands for Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/add-in-commands-for-outlook) article.

Hope it helps you.

Thanks,

Yuki

Comment: please copy description from your link to your answer